# return enum from method in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I have en enum defined like this one:

```
typedef enum{
    apple,
    banana
}Fruits;
```

and I would like to create method that returns this enum like this one:

```
-(Fruits)getFruits;
```

but when I use it like this I got en error: Objective-C message has incomplete result type 'enum Fruits'.

Anyone?

Comment: Import the file that contains the enum definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you're creating the enum might work too, I haven't tried it, but I've always created my enums like this:

```
enum Fruits
{
    apple,
    banana,
    peach,
    pear
};
```

When you create the function, the return value must be `enum Fruits`, not just `Fruits`:

```
-(enum Fruits) getFruits;
```

Also make sure you `#import` the file containing the enum definition. For example if you have a file called `ApplicationEnums.h` that the enum definition is in, add the following line to the top of the file that contains the `getFruits` function:

```
#import "ApplicationEnums.h"
```

Comment: Update 2014. Preferred way now is to use the NS_ENUM macro (see Robotic Cat's answer)

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you haven't imported the file containing the `enum` definition.

As an aside, Apple provide a macro to aid in enum definition and assist with the code completion.  Example:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Fruits) {
    Fruits_Apple,
    Fruits_Banana,
    Anything_you_want
};
```